# php read content from json file and then update

Tags: php, json

I have the following data from an api call:

`$userId = 1234;` and `$accessToken = 6789;`. I want to write this to a json file called `users.json`.

Following this I make another api call and receive the following data:

`$userId = 5678;` and `$accessToken = 0123;`.

I then want to add this to the json file so that it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "1234",
        "accessToken": "6789"
    },
    {
        "userId": "5678",
        "accessToken": "0123"
    },
]
```

My code for writing to the json file looks like this. The `$userId` and `$accessToken` are defined elsewhere and are returning the correct values:

```
$content = file_get_contents('users.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($content, true);
print_r($tempArray); // this doesn;t show anything as the users.json file contains `null`

array_push($tempArray, $userId);
array_push($tempArray, $accessToken);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('users.json', $jsonData);
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. When I view the json file it just contains `null` Can anyone see any error with my code?

Thanks Raul

Comment: can you post this output here $tempArray = json_decode($content, true);  print_r($tempArray); we want know how your json look before updating the value .

Comment: sure, i will add it to the question, still `null` though

Comment: @RaulRodriguez check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. Correct it to look like this

```
 <?php
     $content = file_get_contents('users.json');
     $tempArray = json_decode($content, true);
     if(empty($tempArray)){
       $tempArray = [];
     }
     $newData = [
        "userId" => $userId,
        "accessToken" => $accessToken
     ];
     array_push($tempArray, $newData);
     $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
     file_put_contents('users.json', $jsonData);
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: @CBroe When you encode the array, it  will convert associative array to object so ['x' => 'y'] will become {"x" : "y"}. When you decode an object (in php, the object is converted to an associative array (if 2nd arg to decode function is true) else a Stdclass object (if its false). What i did here is covert the json string to an array of associative arrays. So the above code will definitely work. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to to `json_decode($content, true);` to obtain an array and not an object.

See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Also the `array_push` is not correctly called.

It should be : `array_push($tempArray, ["userid"=>$userId,"accesstoken" => $accessToken]);`

Comment: @RaulRodriguez your `array_push` should be : `array_push($tempArray,
 ["userid"=>$userId,"accesstoken" => $accessToken]);`

Comment: @RaulRodriguez Try to put `[]` into the `users.json` file before starting to obtain an empty array and not null

Comment: ah ok. The answer above works by WdyDev. how does that code look to you?

Comment: @Esteban it works when i put an empty array in there first

Comment: @RaulRodriguez It does the same than what I did, just that I told you to put `[]` into the file to avoid getting null, in his code he tests that the value you obtain is not null and create the empty array. Basically the same problem we pointed out

Answer (score 0):

You have error in json file so that all suggesion not working remove `,` at end of array. Then try below code :

Your json file should be:

```
[
    {
        "userId": "1234",
        "accessToken": "6789"
    },
    {
        "userId": "5678",
        "accessToken": "0123"
    }
]
```

php :

```
$content = file_get_contents('user.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($content,true);
$new_array = array("userId"=>$userId,"accesstoken"=>$accessToken);
array_push($tempArray, $new_array);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('user.json', $jsonData);
```